# Base Class Reference to Derived Class Object

Tags: vb.net

Want to understand which of the following cases can be interpreted as an example of Base Class Referencing to a Derived Class Object. My understanding is that CASE 1 is indeed an example of the base class reference to derived class object. But i am confused with Case 2. I share the reasons behind my understanding below. Requesting your expert opinion on this:

**CASE 1:** In the following example, both "b" and "new_b" are "Base" class type variables which holds the reference(memory address) to the derived class object "d". Hence I am interpreting both the definitions as a case of Base Class Reference to derived class object. Is my understanding correct?

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim d As New Derived()
        '2 examples of base class reference to a derived class object
        Dim b As Base = DirectCast(d, Base)
        Dim new_b As Base = New Derived()
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class Base
    'Code Block
End Class

Public Class Derived
    Inherits Base
    'Code Block
End Class
```

CASE 2: Code mentioned below -- When the Me.testMethod() line gets executed in the useMe procedure in the base class, the ME refers to the current instance *testObj* which is of the *derivedClass* type. I am confused as to whether this can be interpreted as a case of base class reference to a derived class object. The key point of confusion is the following: Just because ME is written inside the base class, whether to interpret ME as a base class type variable (something similar to the variables "b" and "new_b")  that holds reference to the testObj which is a derived class object?

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim testObj As New derivedClass()
        Console.Write("Using Me Keyword:       ")
        testObj.useMe()
        Console.Write("Using MyClass Keyword:  ")
        testObj.useMyclass()
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class baseClass
    Public Overridable Sub testMethod()
        Console.WriteLine("Base Class String")
    End Sub

    Public Sub useMe()
        Me.testMethod() 'Does this line represent a base class ref to a derived class obj?
    End Sub
    
End Class


Class derivedClass : Inherits baseClass
    Public Overrides Sub testMethod()
        Console.WriteLine("Derived Class String")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case 1 in the question, yes it is an example of a base type reference to a derived type instance. It's pretty simple stuff. A common example is a `Control` variable referring to any type of control, e.g. a `Button` or a `TextBox`. Let's say that you have a method that handles an event for a `Button` and for a `TextBox`. You could cast the `sender` parameter as type `Control` and it would work for both. You could then get the `Text` property of the control via the reference, because `Text` is a member of the `Control` class. It would work exactly the same way regardless of the type of the control.

Your second case isn't relevant. You're talking about code inside one of the classes. Talk of a base type reference to a derived type object is only relevant outside both types. You declare a variable of the base type and assign an object of the derived type to it. If you're not doing that then you're not doing a base type reference to a derived type object.

That second code is just about the difference between `Me` and `MyClass`. For the record, I've been coding in VB.NET for almost 20 years and I have never once used `MyClass`, so I would suggest that you don't lose much sleep over it. Also, your second code snippet calls a method that doesn't exist in your code, so that's a problem.